# iOS Application and Share Extension Are Using Different Realm Databases

Tags: ios, swift, realm, share-extension

I've written a small app with iOS 9/Swift 2 and RealmSwift 1.01.  With Realm I just used it out of the box, no special configurations or anything of the like, and the app can insert/update/retrieve data no problem - and I'm using a class specific to do those functions with Realm.
I created a Share Extension set up the PodFile, Targets, all that good stuff but the extension, using the same class as the application is not reading the same Realm database.  I did a test insert from the Extension (both application and extension being tested in the simulator), and using the Finder and Realm Browser I've found that the app has its copy of a Realm database and the extension has its own copy.  Is there anything specific that I need to do to get the app and the extension working off of the same copy/instance of a Realm database?
Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App Groups` allows two different apps(and their extension) use the same folder. And here is [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19).

Comment: Thanks. I did set up a group they both belong to in the "Capabilities" section of both projects and that works for functionality like user defaults but I'm still seeing the extension instantiating and using it's own Realm database separate from the applications.

Comment: @core_rick71 What's the url that you used for realm? Did it in app group folder?(In both app and extension)

Comment: I didn't.  I'm using it with out of the box config (meaning I'm not setting any config and such), just writing and reading to what I'm expecting is the default.  I'm new to extensions so I'm wondering if there's actual configuration with the app/app ext and/or Realm to get both working off of the app instantiated database.

Comment: Thanks @Lumialxk, figured it out.  In the application AppDelegate application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function it calls I a function I created that sets the file path for the realm database and in the extension's one view controller on viewDidLoad the same code is called.  Now the app and extension are working with the same Realm database.  Thanks for your feedback; please let me know if anything in my explanation looks fishy. Rick